# How does a "static" IEnumerator work in this context? (The code works, but what is it actually doing?)

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I am generating many objects procedurally in my Unity C# app/game such as user interfaces, user profiles, etc. I have made classes which feature static variables/functions to allow this. Everything seems to be working as intended. But there's something I don't understand about how or why they work pertaining to static functions/variables.

For example, here is a sample code I made to illustrate having a button in a "profile" object that if you click it will hide a generated "profile" object.

```
public class GenerateProfile {

    private static IEnumerator showOrHideIENumerator;

    public static VisualElement generateObject() {

        VisualElement objectVE = new VisualElement();
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(); //'hide' button to click
        objectVE.Add(customObject);

        customObject.runButtonFunction += delegate { //ie. adding to an event 'runButtonFunction' inside this custom object
            hideFunction(objectVE, ref showOrHideIENumerator);
        };

        return objectVE;
    }

    private void hideFunction(VisualElement objectToHide, ref IENumeratorToUse) {
        if (IENumeratorToUse != null) {
            MonoBehaviorApp.Instance.StopCoroutine(IENumeratorToUse); //using a monobehavior singleton to run coroutine and stop it first in case already running.
        }
        IENumeratorToUse = hideObject(objectToHide);
        MonoBehaviorApp.Instance.StartCoroutine(IENumeratorToUse); //using a monobehavior singleton to run coroutine once should now be stopped
    }

    IEnumerator hideObject(objectToHide) {
        //function to hide object like for simplicity:
        objectToHide.style.visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Now somewhere else you create multiple instances of this using:

```
VisualElement generated = GenerateProfile.generateObject();
```

## Question

If you then click on the button, what actually happens for each generated object when the fade out function runs?

Is every single copy of this generated object actually using the same `showOrHideIENumerator` or do they each get their own?

The reason I am arranging things like this is so I can then allocate a show or hide function to the same IEnumerator `showOrHideIENumerator` as needed, and stop it if it is already running in either direction. (ie. if you click "hide" while it is half way finished showing, it stops showing, and starts hiding).

I ideally wanted to put `showOrHideIENumerator` inside the `generateObject()` function so that it would make a new one for every generated object to have to itself. However, this wouldn't work.

I suspect what's happening is there is just one `showOrHideIENumerator` for the whole app and all these objects made from `generateObject()` are then sharing it (which is actually fine since I don't need multiple ones running at once).

I'm just curious to better understand how this works. Thanks for any clarity. Or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: Well, why don't you try it? Create some buttons and see if they act individually or not. Also, my guess is that they don't fade at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a quick synthetic test to find out:

```
public class CoroutineTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Tester() {
        // Create a reasonably-unique ID, 
        // so we can distinguish multiple instances of this function running.
        var id = Random.Range(0, 10000);

        // Each frame, print our ID, how many cycles we've done, and the frame.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Debug.Log($"IEnumerator {id}: iteration {i} @ frame {Time.frameCount}");
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Store a single shared instance of this IEnumerator.
    static IEnumerator iEnumerator = Tester();
        
    void Start() {
        // On startup, make a coroutine using this IEnumerator.    
        StartCoroutine(iEnumerator);
    }
}
```

Make a few copies of a GameObject with this script attached, and hit play. You'll generate a log like this:

> IEnumerator 130: iteration 0 @ frame 1 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 1 @ frame 1 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 2 @ frame 1 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 3 @ frame 2 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 4 @ frame 2 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 5 @ frame 2 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 6 @ frame 3 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 7 @ frame 3 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 8 @ frame 3 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> IEnumerator 130: iteration 9 @ frame 4 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

What we learn from this:

- We can see the ID is always the same, so every coroutine spawned from this `IEnumerator` instance is sharing that same instance.
- Anytime *any* coroutine spawned from this `IEnumerator` gets ticked, it advances the state of that shared `IEnumerator` instance.

  From reading the code, we might think this coroutine will take 10 frames to finish. But if we spawn three coroutines sharing an `IEnumerator` instance, then it actually it takes 4. Each time one coroutine ticks it steps the instance forward from wherever it last yielded.

This behaviour is not immediately obvious or intuitive (hence the question), so I'd recommend avoiding it in your code. It's likely to lead to confusion and bugs down the line.

Instead of storing a `static IEnumerator`, try storing a `static Coroutine`. This will represent one instance of the iteration that is also bound to only a single coroutine - even if you make a coding mistake, it won't be possible to spawn multiple coroutines all sharing an underlying instance like in the example above. You can still call `StopCoroutine` on it (and it may be more efficient since Unity won't have to look up the coroutine instance from the `IEnumerator`, since you already provided it directly). You can get a `Coroutine` instance by capturing the value returned from `StartCoroutine`.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory. So it appears as I thought - they are all sharing the same static IEnumerator. It is not causing any problems because none are animating simultaneously and even if they were, I am stopping the coroutine before running a new one every time, so only one runs at a time. It does not seem to be any issue. I wonder what you mean though about storing a `static Coroutine`. Even in the Unity documents they refer to Coroutines as being run as `IEnumerator` https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html I do not know how to run a static Coroutine. What would this look like in my code?

Comment: [This is the documentation for the `Coroutine` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html). As I mention in the answer, it's just a matter of capturing the return value when you start the coroutine: `myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(IEnumeratorFunction(maybeWithParameters));`

Comment: Thanks DMGregory. That gave me a much better solution. If I declare a local coroutine in the functions that way and then pass in the coroutine as a reference to other functions so that they can start/stop it or assign new functions to it, it all works perfectly and no need for any static elements that create confusion.

Comment: Reducing global mutable state is usually a win - nice work! Want to share your solution as an answer so others can learn from the technique?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a local Coroutine like:

```
public class GenerateProfile {


    public static VisualElement generateObject() {

        //define animation functions locally
        IEnumerator hideObject(objectToHide) {
                //function to hide object like for simplicity:
                objectToHide.style.visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                yield return null;
            }

        void hideFunction(VisualElement objectToHide, ref CoroutineToUse) {    
            if (CoroutineToUse != null) {
                MonoBehaviorApp.Instance.StopCoroutine(CoroutineToUse); //using a monobehavior singleton to run coroutine and stop it first in case already running.
            }
            CoroutineToUse = hideObject(objectToHide);
            MonoBehaviorApp.Instance.StartCoroutine(CoroutineToUse); //using a monobehavior singleton to run coroutine once should now be stopped
        }

        //assign animation functions
        Coroutine showOrHideCoroutine = null;

        VisualElement objectVE = new VisualElement();
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(); //'hide' button to click
        objectVE.Add(customObject);

        customObject.runButtonFunction += delegate { //ie. adding to an event 'runButtonFunction' inside this custom object
            hideFunction(objectVE, ref showOrHideCoroutine);
        };

        return objectVE;
    }
```